# Lucene -Lexical error while parsing Proximity query

Tags: lucene

I write a code for dynamic search on a database while using lucene.net.
I started creating queries and find the position of the results, It worked great!!
but when I used Proximity Searches, I get an error:

> Lexical error at line 1, column 72.  Encountered:  after : "\"  "

my Searching function:

```
  private static List<String> GeneralSearch(string txt, Table type)
    {
        txt= "10~" + txt;
        string newQuery = "";
        foreach (var field in fields[type])
        {
            newQuery += field + ": " + txt + " OR ";
        }
        newQuery = newQuery.Substring(0, newQuery.Length - 4)+"  ";
        parser.MultiTermRewriteMethod = 
        MultiTermQuery.SCORING_BOOLEAN_QUERY_REWRITE;
        BooleanQuery bq = new BooleanQuery();
        Query query = parser.Parse(newQuery);
        bq.Add(query, Occur.MUST);
        bq.Add(new TermQuery(new Term("tbl", type.ToString())), Occur.MUST);
        TopDocs hits = searcher.Search(bq, reader.MaxDoc);........
```

The "txt" variable contained a query like that:
txt= "I like to read" 
The function create a new query for searching on all the field of specific table

> title: 10~"I like to read" OR content: 10~"I like to read"

I think my problem is maybe that the language alignment was right to left.
If you have an idea, it will help me !!

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak to the specific error, however your query is malformed in two  ways

- The slop (proximity) operator *must* trail a query not lead the query
- Literal phrase queries *must* be enclosed with double quotes

It's wise to log the result of a query parse with Query.ToString().  Assuming StandardAnalyzer, your query is parsing to something like this:

> (text:10~0.5 text:i text:like text:read) +tbl:*somevalue*

What you think is your slop is parsed as a term query with the default slop value of 0.5

> text:10~0.5

and what you thought was a phrase query is in reality parsing to multiple term queries because your phrase is not double quoted:

> text:i text:like text:read

You want your raw query to look something like this:

> text: "I like to read"~10

Here's a nice guide regarding [Lucene query syntax](http://www.lucenetutorial.com/lucene-query-syntax.html).  Good luck!

Comment: You rigth I need to append "~10" after the query, but It does't  work, when I added space שt the beginning and end of the string, It works !!! , the query now is: " I like to read "~10, but I get new exeption: can not read from a close text reader, if you idea, how to fix it, I will be thankful

Comment: Glad to help.  You should search SO for answers regarding your exception  first and if you don't find an answer, post a new question.  If this answered your question please mark it as answered ;)